# scrollTop suddenly not working for sticky menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, sticky

I had this working with no problems for the entire build of the site. Then, the day I was supposed to launch, the sticky menu stopped working right. The menu is supposed to start at the bottom, scroll to the top, then stick (position: fixed).

Now, it scrolls about 10px and then jumps to the top. Why is the scrollTop distance not calculating correctly?

Live site at [site no longer exists]

Here's the code for the sticky menu. I'm also using JS to set min-height of divs to window height, but haven't included that code here.

```
$(function(){
    var stickyRibbonTop = $('#wrapper-wcf53badf7ebadf7').offset().top;
      
    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyRibbonTop ) {
                    $('#wrapper-wcf53badf7ebadf7').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', 'background-image':'url(http://amarshall.360zen.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/menu-fade-background2.png)'});
                    $('#block-bcf53bf14093931c').css({display: 'block'});
            } else {
                    $('#wrapper-wcf53badf7ebadf7').css({position: 'static', top: '0px','background-image':'none'});
                    $('#block-bcf53bf14093931c').css({display: 'none'});
            }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help! I'm not a JS or jQuery expert yet, so any suggestions for cleaning things up would be appreciated.

NOTE: The site is built on WordPress, so no-conflict mode is in effect.

Comment: An aside that I know isn't helpful just this moment: it's times like this that using version control comes in handy. Earlier this week I had a feature suddenly stop working on me, and after rolling back a few commits I found what the problem was.  If you used something like Github (I use Bitbucket), it might help you next time in your debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are initialising the sticky menu function before you set the min-height of `$('big-div')`.

On page load, the menu starts at 54px from the top, and so when you store the `offset().top` value as `stickyRibbonTop`, it is stored at 54px. Then on your scroll event you are comparing against this.

Try setting the `min-height` of the divs first in your code, then run this same script afterwards. The value of `stickyRibbonTop` should then be correct.

Bear in mind that you will need to reset `stickyRibbonTop` every time the `window.height()` is updated, so you should probably make this sticky menu function a named function and call it at the end of the `wrapper_height` function. something like this:

```
function stickyNav() {
    var stickyRibbonTop = $('#wrapper-wcf53badf7ebadf7').offset().top;

    $(window).unbind('scroll', scrollEvent);
    $(window).on('scroll', stickyRibbonTop, scrollEvent);
};

function scrollEvent(event) {
    var stickyRibbonTop = event.data;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyRibbonTop) {
        $('#wrapper-wcf53badf7ebadf7').css({ position: 'fixed', top: '0px', 'background-image': 'url(http://www.adammarshalltherapy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/menu-fade-background2.png)' });
        $('#block-bcf53bf14093931c').css({ display: 'block' });
    }
    else {
        $('#wrapper-wcf53badf7ebadf7').css({ position: 'static', top: '0px', 'background-image': 'none' });
        $('#block-bcf53bf14093931c').css({ display: 'none' });
    }
};

function wrapper_height() {

    var height = $(window).height();
    var wrapperheight = height - 75;
    wrapperheight = parseInt(wrapperheight) + 'px';
    $(".bigDiv").css('min-height', wrapperheight);
    $("#wrapper-wcf53bad125d7d9a").css('height', wrapperheight);

    stickyNav();
}
$(function () {
    wrapper_height();
    $(window).bind('resize', wrapper_height);
});
```

Comment: I added an unbind for the `window.scroll()` event to prevent multiple bindings on `resize()`. For that I have split off the actual event as a separate named function so you can unbind that specific function, rather than unbinding all your functions that are bound to `window.scroll()`. There are neater ways of doing this, but working with the way you have the code set up this seemed the best solution. It would be cleaner to setup a global variable for `stickyRibbonTop` and just update this value on a resize, and leave the actual scroll event untouched.